# Route to a redirect url, after SSO redirect, in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, routes, single-sign-on

I can route to an SSO url with an Apps script, on Google Sheets.

```
function start(){
  var authorize_url = 'https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/authorize/';
  var response_type = '?response_type=code';
  var redirect_uri = '&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/';

  var client_id_val = 'id_string';
  var client_id = '&client_id='+client_id_val;

  var client_secret = 'secret_string';
  var scope = '&scope=esi-assets.read_assets.v1';

  var client_64 = 'clientString';

  var authHeader = 'Basic '+client_64;

  var tokenPOSTUrl = 'https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/token';

  var SSOUrl = authorize_url  
  +response_type
  +redirect_uri
  +client_id
  +scope;

  var options = {
    "followRedirects" : true
  };

  var result = UrlFetchApp.getRequest("http://localhost:4200/auth", options);

  ConnectInventory(SSOUrl);
}

function ConnectInventory(authUrl){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.alert(
    'SSO for inventory upload',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK);

  if(result == ui.Button.OK){

    SSOTab(authUrl);

  };
}

function SSOTab(SSOUrl){
  var html = "<script>window.open('"+SSOUrl+"');google.script.host.close();</script>";
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);   
}
```

After a successful login through the SSO, there is a return address the SSO server tries to route to. In an app, this is routed to a component, which does something with the result.

I am getting nothing, however, when the SSO is completed successfully. Is there any way to accomplish the return-routing, with Google Sheets and Apps Script?

Comment: Can you elaborate or share some example code/URLs?

Comment: How is the SSO URL being called? What is the data flow? I think what you want to do is possible but I'm trying to better understand what the end-to-end process looks like.

Comment: Added script to the question.

Comment: Redirect_uri should be the script's published url `/exec` or `/usercallback`. Read and practice [this](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: aye, yes! This is what I was looking for. I wasn't sure how to create a callback for the redirect without deploying the whole thing as an app. I will take a look at this.